# RabbitMQ java client connection to several queues

Tags: java, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-rabbit, rabbitmq-exchange

I am using amqp-client-4.0.2
I have one topic exchange which routes messages to several queues
The queues are named in a x.x.x.x convention
My java client needs to be able to consume messages from several queues. 
I would like to be able to do that in my spring config for example, to be able to specify a parameter, for example the routing key, or the name convention and the client to be able to consume messages from `animal.orange.#` queues for example. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use wildcards for the queue names; you have to specify each queue fully.

**EDIT**

You could use the REST API to discover the queue names and dynamically configure the container.

Comment: What about that? http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/htmlsingle/#async-annotation-driven. There are several ways to listen to multiple queues actually

Comment: Yes, of course, but you asked about using a wildcard, `animal.orange.#` - rabbitmq doesn't support such a notion; you have to configure each queue in the queues list.

Comment: You are right. I cannot manage to get the payload right though  @RabbitListener(queues = "#{'${rabbitmq.queues}'.split(',')}" )
    public void processOrder(@Payload String data, @Header(AmqpHeaders.CONSUMER_QUEUE) String queue) {